# How do i connect my client App to database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

Typically a **database** has an **administrator** with an **Admin** account, who can create other accounts and give controlled accessibility to those accounts to access databases.  So if someone use **SQL server Management studio (SSMS)** to access the databases or from any other tool either he should be the **admin** or an user who has the access to perform certain operations. Likewise when I have written an app (**C#/Windows forms app**) that has a back end database, the app uses the credential in the `connection string` to gain access to database in **SQL server 2008R2 developer edition** (this is what I use). But at the moment my `connection string` has **Admin** level access **user/password and other credentials** to database which is a disaster to give out. so I have the following question

1. Likewise those accounts in the `SQL server` that have access permissions, do I have to create a separate account for my client app that will and only this client app account has the access to database?

*I asked this because **SQL Admin** can view any database table and their contents, also there can other account configure in **SQL** that can have accessibility to databases and table. So If I want to make this application to connect to its back end database safely, I should make sure that from the client side only this application has the access and no other client or 3rd party database access tool can access my database.*

2. If I need to create a separate account in the database for the client app, How do I do it? Please give me in details!
3. What is the industry standard for making these database connections?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can either give each individual user access to the database (perhaps limiting permissions to not allow them to modify db objects), then use Integrated security, or create one special user that you configure to have read only access to the tables/views/stored procedures that the application needs. This username/password combo would be stored in app.config, and if it is distributed, you can look into encrypting those credentials.
2. Refer to the [SQL Documentation on how to do this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx). It is quite comprehensive.
3. I've been in industry for over 15 years, and I have seen it done both ways in all types of environments, and it really depends on who wants to manage the users, and how easy or difficult that approach is in the given business environment.